# Google Play Store: How to access in app purchases from multiple devices?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have an android app that allows users to purchase managed products by using the [Google Play billing library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate). What I want to do is to authenticate users via Firebase, which I've already done, and link the products they purchase to their Firebase accounts so that it is accessible on other devices as well. What would be an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By using [setObfuscatedAccountId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setobfuscatedaccountid) and [setObfuscatedProfileId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setobfuscatedprofileid), you are able to specify an obfuscated string that is uniquely associated with the user's account and profile (if applies) in your app. I think you can pass their Firebase accounts here when initiating the purchase flow, and then retrive the values back from [getAccountIdentifiers()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#getAccountIdentifiers()) for accurate purchase attribution.

Comment: So for instance, if a user purchases an in app product when logged in with account A in Play Store and also uses the same account for Firebase login in app and if the user switches to account B and removes account A in Play Store but is still logged in as account A in app using Firebase authentication, would the user still be able to access its purchases correctly by using getObfuscatedAccountId method?

Comment: It‘s not Play who attribute the purchase to the user, it's the app developer. So when purchase completed, you will be able to fetch back the obfuscated account id (which is account A), and then do the attribution to account A by your own logic.